# Searching Pandas column for words in list and adding found words into new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words as well as a dataframe

```
data = {'test':['dog is happy', 'dog is hap', 'dog is hap']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

list = ['dog', 'hap', 'happy']

df 
           test
0    dog is happy
1    dog is hap
2    doggy is hap
```

I'd like to add a column let's call it 'words' so that it will look for the **whole** word if it's present in the row. If it is, I'd like to add that word to the words column.
My requested output would be

```
df

           test      words
0  dog is happy  dog happy
1  dog is hap    dog hap
2  doggy is hap  hap
```

I've found that some posts on SO will return 'hap' on the first line because 'happy' begins with 'hap'. (same concept with dog and doggy in third row) I've also found examples that would return True/False in the words column but I would like to have the actual words in that column. Thanks and glad to clarify any points of confusion.

Comment: Heads up, your code for your dataframe does not produce the dataframe you show. There is no `"doggy"` in the `data` you provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward using `set.intersection`:

```py
>>> words = {'dog', 'hap', 'happy'}
>>> df["matches"] = df["test"].str.split().apply(set(words).intersection)
>>> df
           test       matches
0  dog is happy  {happy, dog}
1    dog is hap    {dog, hap}
2  doggy is hap         {hap}
```

Of course, if you want your matches in a specific order or as single whitespace-separated words, this won't do, but you probably *don't* won't those things...

Comment: `df["test"].str.split().apply(set(words).intersection).str.join(' ')` gives them with a single whitespace.

Comment: Yes, it's simple to do that, however in my opinion it's less useful to store the matches in that format. Not sure what OP wants to do with this information, but it seems much better to me to leave the matches as individual words.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `str.findall()`

```
df.assign(words = df['test'].str.findall('|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(i) for i in l])).str.join(' '))
```

Output:

```
           test      words
0  dog is happy  dog happy
1    dog is hap    dog hap
2  doggy is hap        hap
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

```py
filter_words = ['dog', 'happy', 'hap']
def add_words(x):
    return ' '.join([
        token 
        for token in x.split(' ') 
        if token in filter_words
    ])

df['words'] = df['test'].apply(lambda x: add_words(x))
```